# Persisting a date property for a calendar

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, redux, vuex

Need to some advice.
Currently I have a calendar that has one route "/events" (it is a monthly display). Within this route the user can click <<< or >>> to look at different months, in some cases the user will go back many months until they find the event they are looking for (yes there is also a search feature in place), in any given month a user can click into an event ("/events/:id") on a given day to see it's details. 
Problem: since it's one route, when the user clicks back it goes to the current date which is initialized when the component is loaded and **not** to the last month they were on, which means the user would now need to click back <<< a whole bunch of times to get where they need. 
Basically what I think I need is to persist the date of the month that's clicked into, but that leads me to other issues such as how do I get rid of this state when the user leaves the page altogether for another section of the site. Any suggestions? The other issue is that the user can actually get to this event from other areas of the site so I need to differentiate based on where the user came from.

Comment: Please add code showing what you have tried so that users may assist you in debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using local storage, which is a good way to persist state without making calls to the db. This is only good if the data does need to be secured.